# Any 'Server mode' for El Captain

Tags: macos, performance, osx-el-capitan, optimize

We have a virtual machine on vSphere with OS X El Captain installed, which serves as CI server (runs Jenkins instance for building apps we develop).

However, virtual machine looks to be about low-performace in most cases and I'm wondering if there is any 'server mode' setting for OS X, by enabling which all the 'consumer' stuff will be shut down (iTunes, Photo, iCloud and many other unneeded for server stuff)?

Any other ways to achieve this (running only OS X components really required for Server instance)?

Comment: Is your vSphere running on Apple hardware? If not, I think you may be breaching the licensing of OS X...

Comment: I assume you already purchased [OS X Server](http://www.apple.com/osx/server/specs/)?

Comment: @leinad13 yep, I do read licensing agreements

Comment: @Ramhound, yes we have it installed - it comes for free for users with Developer accounts; but it just adds extra services to the host, it doesn't disable unnecessary stuff

Comment: It is best to disable the stuff you don't want to run yourself.  Given OS X Server is a very niche program, there might be tools to help you do that, I would try to find one of those.  If you can't easily find one then it likely does not exist.